# how to test if a particular control has focus?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

i have access 2007 form and i want to test if a particular control (toggle button) has the focus ,

something like :

```
if gotfocus(mytoggle) then
dosomething
endif
```

or maybe like :

```
if me.mytoggle.setfocus = true then
dosomething
endif
```

I have searched and cannot find this , can someone tell me what is correct top to do this ?

Comment: Does `Application.Caller` work in Access?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This for the current form:

```
If (mytoggle Is Me.ActiveControl) Then
```

This for the current Access.Application:

```
If (mytoggle Is Screen.ActiveControl) Then
```

Be careful, if no control has focus, *.ActiveControl may not exist.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code - I've tried to account for .ActiveControl not existing.

```
Private Function isCurrentControl(thisControl As Control) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo err_handler
    
        If Not Me.ActiveControl Is Nothing Then
            If (Me.ActiveControl Is thisControl) Then
                isCurrentControl = True
            Else
                isCurrentControl = False
            End If
        Else
            GoTo err_handler
        End If
  
close_function:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function
        
err_handler:
        isCurrentControl = False
        Resume close_function

End Function
```

You just need to call the function and set the control as a parameter

```
''EXAMPLE: isCurrentControl(mytoggle)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are situations where the .ActiveControl is ***temporary*** non-existing ! When records are scrolled in a form, the procedure Form_Current() gets run. Already at the beginning, there is no focus anymore – the focus is reset to the previous field only **after** Form_Current() has terminated.

Comment: Is there a solution or workaround to this situation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.